# TP-Link Omada Software Controller password cipher

Tags: mongodb

```
user_name:"test"
password:"NhNq8N6pbpj/GXiTYVP41A=="
```

The plaintext password is "lala". These are properties from JSON document, from mongoDB instance of TP-Link Omada Software Controller.

If anyone has information on the cipher used to decrypt "lala", it would solve my problem. The UI for the software already has a bulk import/export user feature, but it has a bug and is defunct. Has been defunct for many prior versions, not sure since which, and is still defunct in current version 4.4.6.

I can automate *localuser* addition by directly storing user JSON into mongoDB, but the password must be stored using the specific cipher which is not documented and is unknown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That looks like a base64 encoded 16-byte hash.  Perhaps md5?

Comment: @Joe: unfortunately, no. Tried base64 16-byte, and md5, and still no luck. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = com.tplink.omada.common.util.b.a.c(password);
    }
```

> Blockquote

```
    package com.tplink.omada.common.util.b;

 

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

 

public class a {
   private static final Logger a = LoggerFactory.getLogger(a.class);
   private static final byte[] b = new byte[]{73, 30, 95, 35, -84, -65, -98, -76};

 

   public static byte[] a(String var0) {
      try {
         return com.tplink.omada.common.util.b.b.b(var0);
      } catch (Exception var2) {
         a.error(var2.toString(), var2);
         return null;
      }
   }

 

   public static String a(byte[] var0) {
      try {
         return com.tplink.omada.common.util.b.b.c(var0);
      } catch (Exception var2) {
         a.error(var2.toString(), var2);
         return null;
      }
   }

 

   public static String b(byte[] var0) {
      return new String(k.b(var0, 0), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   }

 

   public static byte[] b(String var0) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
      Object var1 = null;
      KeyGenerator var2 = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      SecureRandom var3 = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
      var3.setSeed(var0.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      var2.init(128, var3);
      SecretKey var4 = var2.generateKey();
      byte[] var5 = var4.getEncoded();
      return var5;
   }

 

   public static byte[] a(String var0, String var1) {
      try {
         SecretKeySpec var2 = new SecretKeySpec(b(var1), "AES");
         Cipher var3 = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
         byte[] var4 = var0.getBytes("UTF-8");
         var3.init(1, var2);
         return var3.doFinal(var4);
      } catch (Exception var5) {
         a.warn(var5.toString(), var5);
         return null;
      }
   }

 

   public static byte[] a(byte[] var0, String var1) {
      try {
         SecretKeySpec var2 = new SecretKeySpec(b(var1), "AES");
         Cipher var3 = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
         var3.init(2, var2);
         return var3.doFinal(var0);
      } catch (Exception var4) {
         a.warn(var4.toString(), var4);
         return null;
      }
   }

 

   
   // ========== begin password fiasco =============
   public static String c(String var0) {
      if (var0 == null) {
         return null;
      } else {
         byte[] var1 = a(var0, b(b));
         return a(var1);
      }
   }
  // ============ end password fiasco =============

 

   public static String d(String var0) {
      if (var0 == null) {
         return null;
      } else {
         byte[] var1 = a(var0);
         byte[] var2 = a(var1, b(b));

 

         try {
            return new String(var2, "UTF-8");
         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var4) {
            a.warn(var4.toString(), var4);
            return new String(var2);
         }
      }
   }
}
```